# Renewal function equivalence

Tags: stochastic-processes, expectation

I know that $m(t)=E[N(t)]$ for a Renewal process that has $N(t)$ arrivals.

I've seen at my class that there is a way of calculating $m(t)$ by doing $m(t)=\sum_{i=1}^\infty P(N(t)\geq i)$. But I also know that by the definition of Expectation: $E$, $m(t)=E[N(t)]=\sum_{i=1}^\infty P(N(t)=i) i$.

Where am I missing something to find that $P(N(t)\geq i)=P(N(t)=i)i$?

Comment: Have a look at here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_value#Formulas_for_special_cases

Comment: Thanks! This makes sense since the values of $N(t)$ are non negative!